# chrome said server's IP address could not be found

Tags: laravel-5.5, laragon

Im trying to browse my project in laravel using chrome

but chrome said `server's IP address could not be found`

Does anyone encounter the same problem?

I'm running a server on windows 10 with laragon
apache
mysql

Comment: A comment from a deleted answer: They had the same problem, but exiting their antivirus solved it for them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush DNS:

```
ipconfig /release  
ipconfig /renew  
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear your `Host Cache`, which will solve the problem if it is being caused by an Extension. To clear out your cache: enter Incognito Mode in Chrome by pressing the three vertical dots in the top right of the page, and clicking `New Incognito Window`.

In the URL bar, enter `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and press `Enter` on your keyboard. On the screen, look for the `Clear Host Cache` button. Next, open up a command window by finding by pressing `Start` and choosing `Run`. In the text field, type `cmd` and then enter `ipconfig /flushdns`